# How do I do a comparison in the WHERE clause with a value that is nullable?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework-6

In my LINQ query, I am working over a table where it has a value, id, that is nullable int. I have a value, currentId, outside of the query that is an int. I need to do a query on the table to get the entries where id.Equals(currentId). But it keeps giving me an System.NotSupportedException.

My partner and I are struggling with finding a work around this problem since all the posts we found googling are cases where the nullable is not from the entry itself.

Our code is roughly like this:
`var val = (from row in db.OurTable where row.id.Equals(currentId)).SingleOrDefault();`

Comment: Can you please add full text of error? Also have you tried just `row.id == currentId`?

Comment: I've tried it with using the == operator instead. The error I get is the following(with some modification):`System.NotSupportedException: 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'OurTable get_Item(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.'` In this case, OurTable refers to its class name.

Comment: This error message is strange... If the row.id is int, the reasonable error message would be 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method '**Int32** get_Item(Int32)' instead of **OurTable**, could you please check the type of row.id once again?

Comment: Double-checking it, its type is Nullable<int>

Comment: Can you please add the definition for `OurTable`.

Comment: And code for `currentId`.

Comment: The code for currentId is ```int? currentId = Int32.Parse(results[i].id);```

Comment: The definition for OurTable is type DbSet<DataTable>. DataTable is just a class where it contains one attribute: Nullable<int> id. Apologies for the way I'm laying this out right now with types. I'm having to change the names of some fields to hide information related to what I'm working on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I fixed it? My code runs and seems to work. It seems like it had to do with a bool comparison in the WHERE clause I left out that should've always returned true. What that comparison was specifically was checking if another attribute of results[i] was equal to itself.

I added it to match the query my boss gave me but it seems like it caused errors. Sorry this ended up being a dumb question.